# Issue using JSONpath syntax in jq while converting JSON to CSV

Tags: syntax, jq, jsonpath

I'm trying to convert this JSON to CSV with some condition. And my condition is "type" should be "secondary". It should display the field having type secondary. Getting error with below cmd.

```
jq -r '["color","category","type"], ([?type=="secondary"].colors | [.color, .category, .type]) | @csv' test.json > test.csv
```

```json
    {
      "colors": [
        {
          "color": "black",
          "category": "hue",
          "type": "primary",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
            "hex": "#000"
          }
        },
        {
          "color": "white",
          "category": "value",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
            "hex": "#FFF"
          }
        },
        {
          "color": "red",
          "category": "hue",
          "type": "primary",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [255,0,0,1],
            "hex": "#FF0"
          }
        },
        {
          "color": "blue",
          "category": "hue",
          "type": "primary",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [0,0,255,1],
            "hex": "#00F"
          }
        },
        {
          "color": "yellow",
          "category": "hue",
          "type": "primary",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [255,255,0,1],
            "hex": "#FF0"
          }
        },
        {
          "color": "green",
          "category": "hue",
          "type": "secondary",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [0,255,0,1],
            "hex": "#0F0"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have appears to be a JSONPath syntax (https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) , which is not applicable in `jq` which has its own DSL syntax

For this specific case to filter on a condition, you need a `select` statement

```
[ "color", "category", "type" ], 
( .colors[] | select( .type == "secondary" ) | [ .color, .category, .type] ) | @csv
```

<sup>[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yEzcotWrMS)</sup>

Comment: Hello Inian.. Actually your cmd is working with jq.. just now I tried.. its working fine.. Thanks for your help !
jq -r '["color","category","type"], (.colors[] | select( .type == "secondary" ) | [ .color, .category, .type] ) | @csv' test.json > test.csv

Comment: Inian.. If I want to put both the types in select condition.. How to write them ? I tried with &&, its not working..
[ "color", "category", "type" ], (.colors[] | select( .type == "primary" && "secondary" ) | [ .color, .category, .type] )

Comment: @gamer_rulez: Suggest consulting the manual, you could do `select(.type == "secondary" or .type == "primary")`

Comment: (or) (and) both are working.. Different scenario here.. I'm trying to ignore both primary and secondary type using 'or'. But in my output, I'm getting all the types.. little confused.. [It should ignore either primary or secondary, but here its accepting both.. If I give 'and' in place of 'or', its working fine - ignoring both] 
`select( .type != "primary" or .type != "secondary" )`

Comment: If you have more clarifications, please ask a separate question